# How can I change Twitter's Share button height?

Tags: button, twitter, share

How can I change Twitter's icon height?

I have another custom image, but the height stays the same. How do I fix this?

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button and I used the div method and not the iframe because I wanted to add the data-title

I used this code:

```
<script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>
   <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"
      data-url="https://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button"
      data-via="your_screen_name"
      data-text="Checking out this page about Tweet Buttons"
      data-related="anywhere:The Javascript API"
      data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use your own button by using Share Link

`<a href="https://twitter.com/share">Tweet</a>`

> Query String Parameters are

- url     (URL of the page to share)
- via     (Screen name of the user to attribute the Tweet to)
- text    (Default Tweet text)
- relatet (Related accounts)
- count   (Count box position)
- lang    (The language for the Tweet Button)
- counturl (URL to which your shared URL resolves)
- hashtags (Comma separated hashtags appended to tweet text)
- size  (The size of the rendered button)

You can find further details at [Tweet Buttton](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button)