# Tweet button iframe size 107px

Tags: html, iframe, twitter, share

I'm trying to get the tweet button from twitter to work but the iframe generated by the code always gives me a width of 107px by default... I'd like the size of the iframe to change according to the button real size... I can change that via css but giving it a width size of auto doesnt work...

thank you guys

Answer (score 2):

You can control somewhat the rendering of the Twitter button in an iFrame. You can add a `size` attribute to the call and it will give you a couple of versions of sizes you can choose from.

For example:

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
        src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?size=medium"
        style="width:130px; height:20px;"></iframe>
```

The sizes are *MEDIUM, LARGE*

for a complete reference see the [Tweet Button documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button)

also, because it's [poorly documented](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5415). For help with adding parameters to the iFrame version of the tweet button see [this note](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/twitter-development-talk/gr5XkY3dqYs/v0iLNLUusw4J) by a Twitter Developer advocate.

similary, look here [How can I change Twitter's Share button height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121119/how-can-i-change-twitters-share-button-height)

Comment: To get the large size, `size=large` doesn't work for me, but `size=l` (lowercase "L") does.